# New job, Giant project

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, project

So, I just started a new job a few weeks back. It is my first job doing software, and I have been tasked with learning how a giant project works. Now, the guy before me left NO (zilch) documentation or comments anywhere in the source code. In addition, he applied basically EVERY design pattern in the famous *design patterns* book by Gamma, etc...

My question is, how do I start? I have tried setting break points for certain calls that I want to learn (learn bit by bit), but because of the 5 million design patterns employed, every call goes up about 7 levels just to finish, and by then, it's hard to keep track of the 20 some objects being created and used.

Has anyone had a similar experience? A few pointers on different methods to try?

Specs:  language - VB.net
        IDE - Visual Studio 2010
        Using - Windows Forms
        Brain - Melting

Comment: This really belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, I have experience in this exact situation, but we had a bug tracker and I did maintenance for 3-4 months.  When you say "how do i start?"  It depends, what is expected of you? Is the application in production?

Comment: Can you tell me which is the company that gives a 'giant' software project to a 'first time programmer' without any support? Good luck!

Comment: Anyways I just re-read your question, and I'd start with the data model, and how it relates to your business objects.  And I'd probably play around with the UI to see how a user uses your product

Comment: Perhaps you can try some tools to generate documentation. They just might get you a level up over the details. One with good reviews - http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsdoc.shtml

Comment: @Steve - haha, I agree. I am the only software person in this small company. Everyone else is electrical engineer, CAD, or makes low level firmware. So, kind of unique I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting a large project without documentation is always a huge pain in the ass. I hope you have already accustomed your manager to the inconvenient truth that it will take several weeks or even months until you can maintain that project efficiently.

I would start with creating some [UML class diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram). That could tell you a lot about how the system works and which design patterns are used where.

While doing so, I would also add comments to the code with everything I learned about it. When I am not sure if I understood what the code does correctly, I would add a common string like "NOT_SURE" to the comment. Later, when I have a better understanding of the system, I could use a text search to find and revise these comments.

Comment: Thanks Philipp. There is a 'class diagram' feature in VS 2010 that shows what classes are related. I will document on that and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: It's likely that you would learn more when you would create that diagram yourself. Especially because auto-generated diagrams are often arranged very weirdly, so that they cause even more confusion.